# powershell don't recognize vscode 'code' command

Tags: visual-studio-code

I registered the 'code' command in PATH, and in cmd and GitBash the command works but in powershell not.
Does anyone know if i need to register somewhere else to be able to use the vscode command in powershell?

@EDIT:
powershell apparently doesn't read directories correctly even in version 7.1

the command 'code' returns:

```
D:\Program : O termo 'D:\Program' is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, script file or program name
operable. Check the spelling of the name or, if a path has been included, see if the path is correct and try
again.
In line: 1 character: 1
+ D:\Program Files\VSCode-win32-x64-1.52\bin\code.cmd
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\Program:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

the command 'yarn -v' returns:

```
x86: The term 'x86' is not recognized as a cmdlet name, function, script file or operable program. Check the
spelling the name or, if a path has been included, check that the path is correct and try again.
In line: 1 character: 19
+ C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.cmd -v
+                   ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (x86:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Did you restart powershell after configuring the path?

Comment: yes, but don't worked =/

Comment: Try restarting your PC and see if it works

Comment: apparently it is the powershell that is not able to read directories that contain space.